# Javascript - Combinação de variáveis - Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando de uma dica. Não sou programador, mas gosto de me arriscar automatizando processos, me desculpem se a pergunta for básica demais.

Estou trabalhando com a ***API do Google Maps***, e em determinado ponto necessito realizar um filtro para segmentar o conteúdo da minha `InfoWindow`.

Possuo um mapa com vários filtros, que se aplicam aos marcadores e devem se estender ao conteúdo da `InfoWindow`.

Fazendo desta forma, estou pegando **o conteúdo completo** do `JSON ards` e imprimindo na `InfoWindow`, sem segmentar os filtros.

```
// Busca armario no segundo arquivo JSON
var as=$(ards).filter(function (i,n){
    return n.ARMARIO_ERB===marker.getTitle();
});

for (var i=0;i<as.length;i++)
{ .... }
```

Possuo uma série de filtros, que segmentam meus marcadores, mas gostaria que no conteúdo da `InfoWindow` apareçam somente os registros referentes aos filtros.

```
//informação dos selects
var cluster = $( "#CLUSTER-select" ).val();
var cliente_recente = $('#cli_re-select').val();
var tipo_cli = $('#tipo_cli-select').val();
var tipo_reclama = $('#tipo_recla-select').val();
```

Gostaria de uma maneira de aplicar os filtros neste ponto, testando se forem diferentes de ZERO aplica no .`filter`.

```
// Busca armario no segundo arquivo JSON
var as=$(ards).filter(function (i,n){
    return n.ARMARIO_ERB===marker.getTitle() && n.DESC_CLUSTER===cluster;
});
```

Ir adicionando os `&&` conforme os filtros vão sendo selecionados.

Existe alguma maneira mais pratica de fazer isto sem ter que criar um monte de `IF` aninhados testando as combinações?

Posso selecionar um filtro apenas, ou dois, três e etc, são independentes.
Aí está uma amostra de 4 apenas, possuo em torno de 10. Como posso fazer isto de maneira mais eficiente?

**----------------- Atualização ----------------**

Voltei do almoço com uma ideia, porém não funcionou direito.

Criei a seguinte estrutura:

```
var combina = [];
combina = [];

if(cluster !== '0') {
    combina.push('DESC_CLUSTER;' + cluster);
}
if(cliente_recente !== '0') {
    combina.push('CLIENTE_RECENTE;' + cliente_recente);
}
if(tipo_cli !== '0') {
    combina.push('TIPO_CLIENTE;' + tipo_cli);
}
if(tipo_reclama !== '0') {
    combina.push('TIPO_RECLAMACAO;' + tipo_reclama);
}

var filtro_add;
filtro_add = "1 = 1";

for(var i=0;i<combina.length;i++){
    var split;
    split = combina[i].split(';');
    filtro_add += " && n." + split[0] + " === " + '"' + split[1] + '"';
}
```

Resultado do `filtro_add`: `1 = 1 && n.DESC_CLUSTER === "CURITIBA" && n.TIPO_CLIENTE === "SOHO"`

E adicionei esta variável no meu filtro:

```
// Busca armario no segundo arquivo JSON
var as=$(ards).filter(function (i,n){
    return n.ARMARIO_ERB===marker.getTitle() && filtro_add;
});
```

Mas não funcionou, ele não aplica os valores ao resultado.
Se eu colocar os campos na mão funciona. Exemplo:

```
return n.ARMARIO_ERB===marker.getTitle() && n.DESC_CLUSTER === "CURITIBA";
```

Como posso transformar esta `String`?

**----------------- Atualização ----------------**

Depois de muito pesquisar, achei uma alternativa, porém com um péssimo desempenho e possíveis problemas, o pessoal não recomenda muito o uso.
Através do `eval()`

Adicionei ao campo de busca.

A String ficou assim: `filtro_add`: `n.ARMARIO_ERB===marker.getTitle() && n.DESC_CLUSTER === "CURITIBA"`

```
// Busca armario no segundo arquivo JSON
var as=$(ards).filter(function (i,n){
    return eval(filtro_add);
});
```

Funciona, porém com um péssimo desempenho.

Existe alguma outra alternativa?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui realizar o filtro.

Pensando com mais calma, pareceu até óbvio. Vivendo e aprendendo.

Segue exemplo de como fiz:

```
//informação dos selects
var cluster = $( "#CLUSTER-select" ).val();
var cliente_recente = $('#cli_re-select').val();
var tipo_cli = $('#tipo_cli-select').val();
var tipo_reclama = $('#tipo_recla-select').val();                   

// Busca armario no segundo arquivo JSON
var as=$(ards).filter(function (i,n){
var filtro_add=true;

if(cluster !== '0') {
    filtro_add = filtro_add && n.DESC_CLUSTER === cluster;
}
if(cliente_recente !== '0') {
    filtro_add = filtro_add && n.CLIENTE_RECENTE === cliente_recente;
}
if(tipo_cli !== '0') {
    filtro_add = filtro_add && n.TIPO_CLIENTE === tipo_cli;
}
if(tipo_reclama !== '0') {
    filtro_add = filtro_add && n.TIPO_RECLAMACAO === tipo_reclama;
}

    return n.ARMARIO_ERB===marker.getTitle() && filtro_add;

});
```